# Using filter string A to filter for B in C#

Tags: c#, filter

I'm still a beginner so please bear with me, even if this is a stupid question.

So I'm tasked with solving this little thing here. We have a filterstring and the primary key of a table. Now I'm supposed to use that to filter for the First and Lastname of the entry assigned to that primary key, which I honestly don't know how to get done.

I currently have this

```
filterStr = DBToolbox.add(filterStr, "PKCustomer ="+ _PKCustomer, "AND");
```

Which obviously doesn't do what I want to since we are looking to filter for potential duplicate records.

Comment: I don't get it. Having both a filter AND a primary key at hand is a little strange. The PrimaryKey of a table is totally enough to get exactly one specific record from the database, i.e. one Customer PK = you get zero or one Customer row from Customers table.You don't need any filter here. You got a PK, that's enough. Adding a filter here can only reduce that from 1 row into naught, since the filter may overlap with the PK or may not overlap, but still PK is PK, so one row.

Comment: OTOH, if you want to search for duplicates, a filter-by-name or filter-by-lastname sounds like enough too. That will return many rows, which you can then analyze to find pairs/groups of duplicates.. so.. what problem do you have now, and what you want to achieve? Write that clearly, and if possible, add examples of current tables/rows and desired state. Finally, for things like `DBToolbox.add(`, you should at least say where does it come from (link? your private source)  and/or explain what it does, since `DBToolbox.add` doesn't say much. I can guess it concatenates sql query parts, but hey,..

Answer (score 0):

You should query your data table with a `SELECT` that has a WHERE clause, look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_where.asp) for explanation.
After you issue the `SELECT` command and have found some records you should extract the FirstName and LastName from the found record.